# What's the best way to prevent images with hidden-md or hidden-lg from loading on mobile devices in Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a products page that shows results in masonry format for -md and -lg (medium and large) screens in Bootstrap where images may be different heights - and for -sm or -xs I use equal high images for smaller devices. I have 2 different sets of result divs like this:

```
<div class="results hidden-sm hidden-xs">
 ..
 <img src="https://xxx.cloudfront.net/image_860031517015.jpg" width="300" height="583">
 ..
</div>

<div class="results hidden-md hidden-lg">
 ..
 <img src="https://xxx.cloudfront.net/image_300x300_860031517015.jpg" width="300" height="300">
 ..
</div>
```

The problem is that on both mobile and desktop devices, both image sets are being loaded on the browser, which means slower loading times and more bandwidth. Is there any simple way to load only the images that are visible under the current screen resolution?

I know I could do this with CSS, but the problem is that the results are random from the database so I can't create a CSS record for each and every single image file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to prevent loading of images for specific screen sizes you'll have to use javascript. Basically what you'll want to do is store the url of the image in a data attribute, e.g.

```
<img data-src="/path/to/image.jpg" width="300" height="583">
```

Then use Javascript to detect whether or not it's being viewed on a mobile device (there are thousands of examples of how to do this floating around) and if true you want to do something like this...

```
$('div.results.hidden-md.hidden-lg img').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).data('src'));
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that helped me a lot. I now do a check to see the screen resolution for both mobile and non-mobile and then run that if it matches! :)